# How to set Facebook SDK queries specific to time zones?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, timezone, facebook-php-sdk

I want to be able to pull data depending on the time zone I'm currently located in.

For example, I have this query at the moment:

```
$response = $fb->get('/pageid/insights/page_impressions?period=day')
```

And I get this response:

[image]

But how would I go about showing the data so that it's in `Eastern Time (ET)` format. Otherwise known as `EDT` or `UTC -4`? I'm assuming it's an additional "parameter" added to the query, but what would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't.  All data is aggregated by days according to a fixed offset of UTC-7  (even when the Pacific time zone is on UTC-8).

You could adjust the time zone of the resulting timestamp, but that would be misleading, as the `value` totals would now not truly be matching the days total for the time zone specified.

Really, an API like this (or any operation grouping timestamps by date) should consider a time zone - and that time zone should be specified by full IANA time zone identifier, such as `America/New_York`.  Consider that UTC-4 is not sufficient, because US Eastern Time alternates between EST (UTC-5) and EDT (UTC-4).

You could request Facebook add this feature, but AFAIK they do not currently offer it.

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25626486/634824).